# Implementing generic interface

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface Exec

```
public interface Exec<T, U> {
    U execute(final T context);
}
```

Now can I have a class which implements interface Exec as below

```
public class BatchExec<T, U> implements Exec<List<T>, List<U>>
```

My doubt is Exec accepts T and U as type parameters and in this case we are passing it as List and List but BatchExec expects T and U?

Comment: The `T` and `U` in `BatchExec<T, U>` are completely unrelated to the `T` and `U` in `Exec<T, U>`.  Think of them like method arguments - multiple methods can have arguments with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

As [Oliver Charlesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129570/oliver-charlesworth) pointed out, the the `U` and `T` in the `BatchExex<...>` are different than those in `Exec<T, U>`. I.e. if you declare `BatchExec` like this:

```
public class BatchExec<T, U> implements Exec<List<T>, List<U>>
```

Then the execute method signature will contain `List<T>` and `List<U>`:

```
public List<U> execute(List<T> context)
```

This might be confusing so let's create an `OtherbatchExec` with other type parameters:

```
public class OtherBatchExec<P, Q> implements Exec<List<P>, List<Q>> {
    @Override
    public List<Q> execute(List<P> context) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Just to demonstrate it, you can invoke their constructor the same exact way:

```
Exec<List<String>, List<Integer>> exec = new BatchExec<String, Integer>();
Exec<List<String>, List<Integer>> otherExec = new OtherBatchExec<String, Integer>();
```

For the sake of readability, I added the type parameters to the constructor call too. You can use the [diamond operator](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html) too:

```
Exec<List<String>, List<Integer>> exec = new BatchExec<>();
Exec<List<String>, List<Integer>> otherExec = new OtherBatchExec<>();
```